# Meteor. Did not check() all arguments during call

Tags: exception, meteor

My meteor logs are full of these kind of errors:

```
Exception while invoking method 'updateShotTitle' Error: Did not check() all arguments during call to 'updateShotTitle'
    at _.extend.throwUnlessAllArgumentsHaveBeenChecked (packages/check/match.js:352)
    at Object.Match._failIfArgumentsAreNotAllChecked (packages/check/match.js:108)
    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1596)
    at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648
    at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56)
    at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647
    at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56)
    at _.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:646)
    at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:546
```

This is client code:

```
keypress .info-title-input': (e) ->
     if e.keyCode == 13
          name = $(e.currentTarget).val()
          file_name = @.file_name
          shot_id = @.shot_parent
          check(shot_id, String)
          check(file_name, String)
          check(name, Match.Any)

          Meteor.call("updateShotTitle", shot_id, file_name, name)
```

And also in methods the are checks, but nothing helps me of understanding why this is happening

```
updateShotTitle: (shot_id, file_name, title) ->
    check(shot_id, Match.Any)
    check(file_name, Match.Any)
    check(title, Match.Any)

    Shots.update(
      { shot_id: shot_id, "images.file_name": file_name },
      { $set: { "images.$.title":  title  } }
    )
```

And this is not the only method that gives me such errors, almost all of them throw this kind of exceptions. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: One way this can happen is if you pass more arguments than the function expects. E.g. `Meteor.call("updateShotTitle", 1, 2, 3, 4)`. Is this the only place in your app where `updateShotTitle` is called?

Comment: I checked everything, no more arguments are passed. Though I have this method called in some other place on client where there is no check. I'll try to put some checks there and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @doomie, your last comment makes no sense. The check is (should be) done in the method on the server, and not on the client where the call is made.

Comment: @PeppeL-G, hmmm... I had check() in the method on the server and it was throwing exceptions. Now I have check()'s on the client  before Meteor.call() and no exceptions are popping out. I did after the exception said:  "Did not check() **during the call** " Strange ... :/

Comment: Not sure how the check message is triggered, but you pass an argument `name` in the call and it is named `title` in the check. Do you still see exceptions if you use the same identified on both?

Comment: @Stephan, I am also not sure how check works, but now i added check on argument `name` before the call and in methods the argument is called `title` and everything works fine. Magic... :/